# What is the MaxSimultaneousWorkflows replacement?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, threadpool

**MAIN QUESTION:**

I am using Workflow Foundation 4.0 in which the `WorkflowRuntime` has been replaced by the `WorkflowApplication` as a workflow host for a single instance.

I am looking to control the number of concurrent Workflow instances running simultaneously. In WF 3.5 and earlier, one could set the `MaxSimultaneousWorkflows` property on the `DefaultWorkflowSchedulerService` used by `WorkflowRuntime` and such throttling could be achieved. How can I do the same using WF 4.0?

**BACKGROUND AND WHY I WANT TO DO THIS**

In my application, I want to schedule hundreds of workflow instances concurrently and I am creating a new instance of WorkflowApplication for each of them and calling "run" on the WorkflowApplication in a loop.

Each WorkflowApplication has its own DbContext instance which it uses for persistence and reading of data from SqlServer.

Everything works great when the number of WorkflowApplication threads running simultaneously is reasonably small amount (say couple of dozen instances). However, when I test the app with hundreds of workflow instances scheduled, I am seeing that the SqlConnection being used by DbContext times out waiting for a thread from the ThreadPool.

Hence, I want to throttle the maximum number of WorkflowApplication instances that can run to about 50% of what .Net decides by default so that a reasonable number of threads are still left in the .NET ThreadPool for SqlConnection and Asp.Net (which is also running on the machine in a separate AppDomain).

Comment: Not an answer, but I don't think there *is* an equivalent.  WF4 uses the SynchronizationContext pattern for posting workflows to threads.  You can use the same SC for multiple WA's, so you can create your own implementation of SC to control how many you wish to execute at the same time.

Comment: @Will - is this what you are suggesting? The custom SC would need to monitor a global counter it holds for active WFs and do a Thread.Sleep in a while loop in its 'Post' API if the global counter is above the max workflow threshold and retry after a sleep delay?

Obviously, I will need to maintain this 'counter' in a thread-safe manner. 

I find it bizarre that such an important functionality got dropped with no replacement in WF 4.0 which is forcing such hacky workarounds!

Comment: Thread.Sleep?  Hell no.  And there is nothing hacky about using the same SC to coordinate multiple instances.  Its almost trivial.  You queue them up in a thread safe queue and service the queue with a set number of threads.  The number of threads equals the maximum number of concurrent workflows.  Yes, its different from wf3, but then so is everything.